# Exclude properties from dotCover analysis

Tags: c#, .net, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

How to exclude analysing of empty properties like

```
public string Something { get; set; }
```

from dotCover analysis? What filter should I use?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude auto-properties from coverage analysis, dotCover 2016.2 now provides the Hide auto-properties option to let you do just that.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Reference_Options_dotCover_Filtering.html

Auto properties can be hidden in the "report" and "analyse" commands using /HideAutoProperties from the [console runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/2016.2/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html).

Comment: @Saint did this help? If so, please mark it as the answer; if not, perhaps give what your answer was, or clarify why it didn't help.

Comment: it doesn't work. 1) the link doesn't work, but i found the docs. 2) It can only be configured via Visual Studio. 3) It's not supported in Rider, or dotCover, or dotCover in Team City.

Comment: Thanks for advising about the broken link. I've sought out a replacement link and edited my answer. Auto properties can be hidden in the "report" and "analyse" commands using /HideAutoProperties from the [console runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/2016.2/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html).

Comment: Ahh, the /HideAutoProperties worked, now all that's lacking is Rider support.